# Unable to embedded tomcat war file using command prompt

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have started to add embedded tomcat in to the our spring web application. it is working fine in eclipse.
Now i am trying to start the application using command prompt,it is giving 
following exception

no main manifest attribute ,in order-spring-mvc-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

In my pom.xml file is as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
```

my main class as follows

```
 public class EmbeddedTomcatMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
            String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
            if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
                webPort = "8080";
            }

            tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

            StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
            File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
            WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
            resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                    additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
            ctx.setResources(resources);

            tomcat.start();
            tomcat.getServer().await();
        }

    }
```

it creates only one war file.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot (according to your tags)... Wy start your own tomcat, that is a feature that Spring Boot provides out-of-the-box...

Comment: This is normal spring application.not spring Boot

Comment: Then remove the tag... Also it isn't a normal spring application as the stacktrce clearly states you are using Spring Boot....

Comment: i used spring boot plugin in pom.xml, please suggest me anything wrong..

Comment: If you aren't using Spring boot then why use the plugin? Looks like you are trying to do things and use frameworks you aren't understanding? Either you use Spring Boot (which is what your stack trace looks like) or you aren't and then you shouldn't be using the `spring-boot-plugin` anyway.

Comment: i wnat to add embedded tomcat behaviour to spring web application

Comment: anybody can help on this..

Comment: Then for starters remove all Spring Boot related stuff from your project OR properly use Spring Boot (which will make your life easier as that already has invented and implemented what you want).

Comment: i want embedded support for spring application,i added embedded-tomcat dependencies and i wrote above main method.its working file through eclipse. here problem is i want to run on command prompt. its giving lifecycleexception

Comment: You keep ignoring my requests for information... If you don't want an answer thats fine... As stated either use Spring Boot or not if you don't start removing those dependencies and spring boot plugin. If you want an executable jar/war you will need to play with an uber jar containing the dependencies.... I would however recommend that you simply remove this class and use Spring Boot which would be nothing more then a few dependencies and replacing your class with 2 lines of code.

Comment: actually i need embedded tomcat for my big existing spring 4.0.0 application.,here i need embedded support same application for that,which dependencies i need to add in my pom.xmll

Comment: You need to add tomcat... But as you stated and as the exception clearly shows you also added Spring Boot things... Which will break... So this is the last time I'm going to repeat myself, start by removing the spring boot stuff (or start using it properly).

Comment: now i added only spring support.it is also working fine in eclipse .li am trying to run on command prompt ,its giving no main manifest its saying..

Comment: How exactly do you run it in the command prompt? With what command?

Comment: java -jar order-spring-mvc-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

Comment: i seen other spring boot application ,when we run -->mvn package its creating two war files one is order-spring-mvc-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and order-spring-mvc-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.original
here my case its creating only one

Comment: as stated if you aren't using spring boot you wil have to create your own executable jar file.

Comment: jar and war both the cases its saying same problem

Comment: is there any changes in main method